# Android Studio keeps running old code

Tags: android-studio

The masterpiece called Android Studio is painful to work with: I can't help but seek your help with a following problem:

Once I ran some code, changed it a few times since then, but no changes were actually made and studio keeps running the old code (which does not even exist anymore). After I clean & rebuild the project, it sometimes works and the new code runs, but then after a couple of changes I encounter this trouble again.

Since building/rebuilding and compiling again takes more time than writing code, this is no option for me. I checked some related questions, one advice was to turn on Virtualization in BIOS. I did, but nothing changes.

1. My laptop is Lenovo G50
2. Virtualization is on.
3. Win10 x64
4. Android Studio 2.2
5. MainActivity as configuration (with red cross and "No main method found" sign).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is error in your code and you have selected `run without warning` when error in program exists. In such a case `the last successfully built code` would get pushed! Try doing a clean (`Build --> Clean Project`), if the project now shows up errors you have your culprit, else make sure your XML files are all proper.

> MainActivity as configuration (with red cross and "No main method found" sign).

this can happen in two cases:

1. Your MainActivity class isn't properly added in the AndroidMainfest.xml
2. Your `MainActivity.java` or `activity_main` contains error

make sure to check both of this thing,and then clean your project(Build --> Clean Project).This tells the IDE to delete any previously compiled binaries and rebuilds them. (The APK file).

Comment: Interesting... I don't remember changing anything like this - like running without warnings. Where can I check it ?
And I also couldn't find any error in any of xml files. Neither did cleaning help.
 I created a new project and will try all the possible ways from scratch, so far I leave this question open and will update when something is changed.